# Muenchian Grouping

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This is my XML code:

```
<NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
    <LIGHT_DESCRIPTION_LIST>
        <LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>
             <LIGHT_COLOUR>R</LIGHT_COLOUR>       <-- Colour 1
        </LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>
        <LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>
            <LIGHT_COLOUR>G</LIGHT_COLOUR>        <-- Colour 2
        </LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>
    </LIGHT_DESCRIPTION_LIST>
    <LIGHT_INFORMATION>
        <SIGNAL_SEQUENCE>01.0+(01.0)</SIGNAL_SEQUENCE>
        <SECTOR_LIST>
            <LIGHT_SECTOR>
                <SECTOR1_2>UNKNOWN</SECTOR1_2>   <-- Characteristic 1
                <SECTOR2_2>UNKNOWN</SECTOR2_2>
            </LIGHT_SECTOR>
            <LIGHT_SECTOR>
                <SECTOR1_2>62</SECTOR1_2>        <-- Characteristic 2
                <SECTOR2_2>83</SECTOR2_2>
            </LIGHT_SECTOR>
        </SECTOR_LIST>
    </LIGHT_INFORMATION>
</NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
```

My xslt code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="LIGHT_SECTOR">
    <xsl:variable name="Sectors" select="."/>
    <xsl:text>VIS </xsl:text>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="SECTOR1_2"/>
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="SECTOR2_2"/><br/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This is the output:

VIS UNKNOWN-UNKNOWN
VIS 62-83

I would:

VIS R UNKNOWN-UNKNOWN  <-- concat of "Vis" + Colour 1 + Characteristic 1
VIS G 62-83                 <-- concat of "Vis" + Colour 2 + characteristic 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a grouping issue, not if there is a 1-1 correlation between **LIGHT_DESCRIPTION** and **LIGHT_SECTOR**

Anyway, you can look up the relevant **LIGHT_DESCRIPTION** by means of a key. In this case you want to look them up by their ordering:

```
<xsl:key name="light" match="LIGHT_DESCRIPTION" use="count(preceding-sibling::LIGHT_DESCRIPTION)" />
```

Then, to get the relevant light value when you iterate over your **LIGHT_SECTOR** just use the key to look them up based on the position

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('light', position() - 1)/LIGHT_COLOUR" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="light" match="LIGHT_DESCRIPTION" use="count(preceding-sibling::LIGHT_DESCRIPTION)" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//SECTOR_LIST" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SECTOR_LIST">
        <xsl:for-each select="LIGHT_SECTOR">
            <xsl:variable name="Sectors" select="."/>
            <xsl:text>VIS </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('light', position() - 1)/LIGHT_COLOUR" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="SECTOR1_2"/>
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="SECTOR2_2"/><br/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I had to change the xml file, thanks for your availability.